# Subtract the amount > 100%

Tags: sql-server

I have this stored procedure where it updates the **EtiquetasInventariadas** column with the number of validated items and the **Precisão** Column with a % of how many items were validated compared to the total of items available on **EtiquetasPorInventariar**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spx_UPDATE_EtiquetasInventariadas]
@EtiquetasInventariadas int, 
@InventarioID int,
@LocalizacaoID int 
AS
BEGIN



UPDATE xLocalizacao
    SET EtiquetasInventariadas = EtiquetasInventariadas + @EtiquetasInventariadas, IsValid = 1
    WHERE (LocalizacaoID = @LocalizacaoID)

    UPDATE xLocalizacao
    SET Precisao = CAST(EtiquetasInventariadas AS DECIMAL) / CAST(EtiquetasPorInventariar AS DECIMAL)
    WHERE LocalizacaoID = @LocalizacaoID 

    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM xLocalizacao WHERE InventarioID = @InventarioID AND isValid = 0)
    BEGIN 
        SELECT 1 
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT -1
    END
END
```

However, i was asked that if the number of **EtiquetasInventariadas** are higher than the amount in **EtiquetasPorInventariar** it should subtract the amount beyond 100% and I can't seem to understand the logic how to do this..

**EDIT**

By subtract if value is higher than 100 I mean

If the outcome is 120%, it should show 80%

Here's table definition of xLocalizacao

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[xLocalizacao](
    [LocalizacaoID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Localizacao] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [EtiquetasPorInventariar] [int] NOT NULL,
    [EtiquetasInventariadas] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IsValid] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [InventarioID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Precisao] [decimal](3, 2) NULL
)
```

Comment: I've no idea what "subtract the amount beyond 100%" is meant to mean. If you don't either, it's time to go back to whoever gave you this task to find out *what they mean*.

Comment: Please don't name parameter with *the same name* as a field.  Makes the code unreadable and prone to errors.  Esp. if it is in another language.

Comment: Please post the table definition, as well - I'm particularly interested in the data type of `EtiquetasInventariadas`, since you're casting it before doing a calculation on it.

Comment: Are you saying that if EtiquetasInventariadas > EtiquetasPorInventariar then the result should be limited to 100%? (As opposed to 107%, for example).

Comment: Aren't you simply saying that: `IF @valueA > @valueB THEN take @valueB ELSE take @valueA END`, assuming `@valueB` is the 100% figure and `@valueA` is a figure that will either be < 100% or > 100%?

Comment: Edited main post with table and what i meant with subtracting amount beyond 100

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may not be immediately obvious, but if you want 100% to be the maximum attainable and amounts over are as bad as amount under, then some creative subtractions and [`ABS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/abs-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) help you out.

If you current value is in a variable called `@Precisao` then if it's already a number between 0 - 100 representing the percentage:

```
100 - ABS(100 - @Precisao)
```

If it's a number between 0.0 and 1.0, then:

```
1.0 - ABS(1.0 - @Precisao)
```

Will give you the result you seek.

You can of course replace that variable with your current expression, suitably parenthesized.

From [fooplot.com](http://fooplot.com/#W3sidHlwZSI6MCwiZXEiOiIxLjAtYWJzKDEuMC14KSIsImNvbG9yIjoiIzAwMDAwMCJ9LHsidHlwZSI6MTAwMCwid2luZG93IjpbIi02LjQ5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OCIsIjYuNDk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk4IiwiLTMuOTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5IiwiMy45OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTkiXX1d)

[image]

Comment: it doesn't seem to do anything different from a case with the division inversed on the conditions, it does not work if it's higher than 100, still need to switch the columns on the division

Comment: @Jackal - if I write `80` where I currently have `@Precisao`, I get the result of `80`. If I instead substitute `130` there, I get the result `70`. That seemed to be what you were asking for.

Comment: @Jackal - if you numbers aren't yet percentages but are values between `0.0` and `1.0`, then the magic number to use is `1.0` rather than `100`.

Comment: thanks this worked perfectly and can see it in action

Answer (score 1):

A simple case should work

```
SET Precisao = CASE WHEN EtiquetasInventariadas >= EtiquetasPorInventariar THEN 1.00 ELSE CAST(EtiquetasInventariadas AS DECIMAL) / CAST(EtiquetasPorInventariar AS DECIMAL) END
```

Comment: It must subtract not stay fixed at 100, i updated main post